# How to use our own logs in LogAI tool to log analysis

Tags: logging, log-analysis

I'm searching for the LogAI documentation, for log clustering and log summarization with the help of GUI

I found the below repository

https://github.com/salesforce/logai

Can anyone suggest some more resources for better understanding LogAI

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, **or other off-site resources** are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.